# Adding new node into xml data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, xquery, xquery-sql

```
declare @xml xml =  '<?xml version="1.0"?> <dashboardsettings>   <widgets>
    <widget userwidgetuniqueid="9" widgetid="9" daterange="1" startdate="2016-02-06" enddate="2017-02-06" />
    <widget userwidgetuniqueid="10" widgetid="10" daterange="0" startdate="2016-02-06" enddate="2017-02-06" />
    <widget userwidgetuniqueid="11" widgetid="11" daterange="0" startdate="2016-02-06" enddate="2017-02-06" />
    <widget userwidgetuniqueid="12" widgetid="12" daterange="3" />
    <widget userwidgetuniqueid="13" widgetid="13" daterange="3" />   </widgets> </dashboardsettings>'
```

We wanted to add extra node to this xml (at last or first does not matter) 
    
    output to be as

```
 declare @xml xml = 
    '

        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <dashboardsettings>
          <widgets>
            <widget userwidgetuniqueid="9" widgetid="9" daterange="1" startdate="2016-02-06" enddate="2017-02-06" />
            <widget userwidgetuniqueid="10" widgetid="10" daterange="0" startdate="2016-02-06" enddate="2017-02-06" />
            <widget userwidgetuniqueid="11" widgetid="11" daterange="0" startdate="2016-02-06" enddate="2017-02-06" />
            <widget userwidgetuniqueid="12" widgetid="12" daterange="3" />
            <widget userwidgetuniqueid="13" widgetid="13" daterange="3" />
            <widget userwidgetuniqueid="14" widgetid="14" daterange="3" />
          </widgets>
        </dashboardsettings>

    '
```

--then
     i wrote code to find max value of userwidgetuniqueid and adding +1 and prepared new node also but i could not add this new node to xml value , the error
    says :  Incorrect use of the XML data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context.

```
--below is my code





 declare @TopUserwidgetuniqueid int 
    SELECT top 1 @TopUserwidgetuniqueid = x.y.value('.','int') 
              FROM @XML.nodes('/dashboardsettings/widgets/widget/@userwidgetuniqueid') AS x ( y )
              order by x.y.value('.','int')  desc
    select @TopUserwidgetuniqueid=@TopUserwidgetuniqueid+1

    declare @xNewNode xml = '<widget widgetid="'+cast(@TopUserwidgetuniqueid as varchar(10)) +'" daterange="2"></widget>'

    SET     @xml = @xml.modify('insert sql:variable("@xNewNode") as last into /dashboardsettings/widgets[1]') 
    select  @xml
```

The last xml.modify to insert new node is not working , please help , 
Many thanks.